# BASH for loop multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, for-loop, structure

I am trying to pull info from multiple arrays and then echo it out. Unfortunately, I am having some trouble and I am almost positive it is something wrong with my for loop structure.

Lets assume:

```
array1= 1, 2, 3
array2= toronto, new york, paris
```

The code that I currently have:

```
for element in "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}"
do
echo ""$element" "element""
done
```

The output looks something like this:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
toronto toronto
new york new york
paris paris
```

Now this obviously doesn't work because it outputs the same thing twice in each array. So, I tried to use a for loop within a for loop but then I have multiples.

How would I setup the for loop so my output looks like this:

```
1 toronto
2 new york
3 paris
```

Comment: The definition `array2= toronto, new york, paris` is not valid at all if you want to define an array.

Comment: You can't natively loop over multiple arrays. So you have to manually do it by looping numerically from `0` to `"${#array1}"` (or `"${#array1}"` depending on which is longer and what behaviour you want if they don't have the same length).

Comment: just wanted to put down that the question itself answered what google brought me here for. I wanted to loop over two arrays (sequentially) and didn't know you could just concatenate them like that (`for element in "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}"`), I was about to attempt something silly (`printf '%s\n' "${array1[@]}" "${array2[@]}" | while read....` gross). So thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
array1= 1, 2, 3
array2= toronto, new york, paris
```

should be rewritten as :

```
array1=( 1 2 3 )
array2=( toronto 'new york' paris )
```

And finally :

```
for ((i=0; i<${#array1[@]}; i++)); do echo "${array1[$i]} ${array2[$i]}"; done
```

Comment: This is a very good way to do it. Simple and using the right tools, +1

Comment: Yea this is unreal. Exactly what I was looking for. Very efficient!

Comment: Doesn't look good because u have to make sure that the array has similar naming

Answer (score 1):

You probably want this:

```
array1=(1 2 3)
array2=(toronto "new york" paris)
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${array1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${array2[@]}")
1   toronto
2   new york
3   paris
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr2=("1" "2" "3")
declare -a arr=("element" "element" "element")
x=0
while [ $x -le 2 ]
do
echo " "${arr2[x]}" ${arr[x]}"
 x=$(( $x + 1 ))
done
```

Comment: some additional explanation to your solution would be nice (so other readers can understand it easier). On another matter: you might want to think about changing your user name, people could take it wrong and feel affronted, if you know what I mean.

Comment: yes dude you are rigth I m newbies on linux and this webside. I try to learn just ask question myself how . and I know my nick means I don't accept their behavior even rock earth what else without soul did not deserve vulgarity . I hope my sences are clear eng is not my laguage